# How can I use local mysql data in a mysql container created through docker-compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

My company has been working with local setups of our mysql database for years. We have recently decided to adopting a containerized approach to local development, and we want to add the database into being run in a container. The issue is, because all of our data is already set up locally, we want to be able to just use the same data in the mysql container. I have tried using volumes to mount the directory storing all the mysql data into the container to no avail. Has anyone had success with doing this?

db part of docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - /usr/local/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql
```

I am able to get mysql running fine and am able to connect to it easily from my local machine, but when I connect, none of the local databases that already exist are there. Is there something that I'm overlooking?

Comment: did you try without double quotes in the volumes path?- /usr/local/mysql/data:/var/lib/mysql

Comment: @CaioT Just tried that and still nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@yourknightmares,

So I just ran a test and it worked for me. Here is what I did:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
    command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
      - "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/opt/nginx/nginx.conf"
```

In my host machine, I have the file at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
, then:

```
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker exec -it 02ba7032d699 bash
$ root@02ba7032d699:/# cat /opt/nginx/nginx.conf
#hello
```

The file was mounted just fine from the host to the container. I would suggest you to do the same exercise just for troubleshooting purposes. Also, have you looked at the container logs with **docker logs container_id**?

Comment: I can do it with other folders/files fine, this is specifically an issue with the mysql folder for some reason (have checked permissions and everything, nothing explains it). I've looked through all the logs and there's no errors, and nothing even referencing these directories/files

Comment: MySQL folder should be the same way. If you exec into the container and list the content of /var/lib/mysql will it be empty? Also, is the directory /usr/local/mysql/data a symlink or something?

Comment: If I ssh into the container, then to the /var/lib/mysql directory, it's NOT empty, but doesn't contain any of the non-default databases/files, making me think it's possibly being overwritten or something? Also, yes /usr/local/mysql is symlinked to /usr/local/mysql-<version> so maybe it's having issues pulling out the data directory? Though, I have no issues calling any Unix command on the directory successfully.